# Why is DBL_MIN not negative (in Swift)?

Tags: swift, exponent

Why does the expression `DBL_MIN < 0` returns `false`?
Why do the comparisons against `DLB_MIN` seem to indicate that `DBL_MIN` is positive?

```
let a = DBL_MIN // 2.225073858507201e-308
let b = DBL_MAX // 1.797693134862316e+308

if a < 0.0 {
    print("1. DBL_MIN is indeed less than zero") // doesn't print (unexpected)
}

if DBL_MIN < 0.0 {
    print("2. DBL_MIN is indeed less than zero") // doesn't print (unexpected)
}

if DBL_MIN > 0.0 {
    print("3. DBL_MIN is larger than zero?") // prints (unexpected)
}

if DBL_MIN > DBL_MAX {
    print("4. DBL_MIN did some strange flip?") // doesn't print (OK)
}

if b > 0.0 {
    print("5. DBL_MAX is indeed larger than zero") // prints  (OK)
}

/* printout: 
3. DBL_MIN is larger than zero?
5. DBL_MAX is indeed larger than zero  */
```

I suspect it has something to do with floating point precision, but I can't really explain it myself.

I am using Swift 2.1.1 and XCode 7.2.

Comment: `DBL_MIN` is the smallest *positive* number which is representable as a `Double`, so all your results are expected. Your output `2.225073858507201e-308`even  shows that it is positive...

Comment: @MartinR Of course.. Thanks!

Comment: I do not really care reputation-wise if you delete this, since I did not get any rep anyway, but think you should not delete this question, the downvotes really do not matter at all. The only thing would a better searchable title like "why is DBL_MIN not negative" in addition to the `<` which will not get the essential part of the question search-/findable via google.

Comment: Okay, my "real" SO journey started around 9 months ago, therefore I am not the absolutely right one to ask either. But I think that this is a perfectly fine and valid question.

Comment: @luk2302 I see, thanks for your help and feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not minimal in the sense that is the largest negative number but the number closest to zero representable as `Double`:

```
2.225073858507201 * 10 ^ -308
```

That simply is a positive value. The `-` represents a negative exponent, not a negative overall value.